# LinkedIn SSO: the authorization server encountered an unexpected condition

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, linkedin-api

Since 2AM (ish) this morning, the SSO does no longer work with LinkedIn.

We 100% get the error "the authorization server encountered an unexpected condition".

We did not change our code whatsoever. We tried to switch the LinkedIn developer app to test mode and then back to live mode, but still no luck.

There can be no logs on our end (for the issue is on LinkedIn end), and AFAIK there is no developer log on LinkedIn either (although it could be a pretty useful addition).

Anyone experiencing the same issue? Or anyone have any idea why this could happen all of a sudden?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** after several attempts (by modifying our OAUTH code in some ways), it always failed. And we decided to create another brand new LinkedIn developer app, and it did work! This is really weird...

Comment: We experience the same thing - 100% "the authorization server encountered an unexpected condition" and this has been going on for at least 4 hours. We have 2 apps configured (one for production and one for test, but otherwise mostly identical) and the issue is only affecting our test app. So it would seem only some apps are affected.

Comment: Yeah I don't understand why my question was previously downvoted... Great to see I'm not the only one to encounter this issue (there have been other issues with LinkedIn, example being the profile picture no longer being sent). Have you tried my solution? To create a brand new app?

Comment: I just tried create a new application with LinkedIn and the new ClientID works. The old one still does not. So something is definitely wrong at LinkedIn's end. I have had a hard time locating a way to contact LinkedIn about this. I guess there is not much else to do than hope LinkedIn picks up on this somehow.

Comment: I just tested and the old application now works again. So whatever glitch this was it appears to be fixed now.

Comment: @OleTolshave agreed, the LinkedIn team is supposed to read the SO posts containing the #linkedin tag. As to whether they'll reply to this post and give an explanation or something, no one knows... Thanks for the update about your old application!